# How to use java code in JSP <c:if> condition

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

How to use the value of "ft" in c:if condition.

```
    <% Date dNow = new Date( );
   SimpleDateFormat ft = 
   new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss a zzz");
   out.print( "<h2 align=\"center\">" + ft.format(dNow) + "</h2>");%>
```

Here is my way of using code in **JSP(sample code)**

```
<c:if test="${row.RecvDate}-$(ft) > 48"></c:if> .....
```

**Explanation of  my task**: Need to subtract two date and check the condition is greater the 48 hours, the row should be highlight in green color, otherwise fine (no change).

So I got values from database and doing validation in JSP page for highlighting row as per condition.

Comment: `ft` is a `DateFormat` object. How can you subtract that from a `Date` value you get from your DB?!

Comment: @ R.J :Then how can i subtract ((current date) - (DB col date) )> 48 in JSP page

Comment: something like `${row.RecvDate.time/3600000) - (ft.time/3600000) > 48}`

Answer (score 1):

convert  your date in to integer and subtact it and compare it as you wish

```
 int i = (int) (new Date().getTime());
        System.out.println("Integer : " + i);
        System.out.println("Long : "+ new Date().getTime());
        System.out.println("Long date : " + new Date(new Date().getTime()));


    Integer : 1345619256
    Long : 1345619256308
    Long date : Wed Aug 22 16:37:36 CST 2012
```